# Best structure for a javascript function in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am studying Angular and I wonder what is the best organization for this particular point:

Here is my "fantastic" structure:
[image]

**Subject:** I create a Pagination, and I want to create it with a javascript function.

**Question 1:** Should I create this function in my **component** (gazette.component.ts), or in an **attribute directive** ?

**Question 2:** Should I create this function in javaScript ES6 (not jquery, jquerylite or anything else) ?
What is the best practice for this situation.

Thank you !

Comment: What did you investigate yourself?

Comment: Hello, I can create the function, no problem for that, but i don't know if i need to create an attribue directive and write the function in this directive or create the function directly in my component.
Did you know what is the best practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive is useful when you want to use same piece of code to many dom elements/components. Like you want to focus/highlight some div/paragraph on specific condition.

There can be hundreds of elements in your application that you want to 
implement the same functionality. In this situation you can write a directive.

In your case if you want to implement the pagination functionality with in one component (GazetteComponent ) and encapsulate the codes from other components then you can write the code in this component

Otherwise go for a directive.

> Also see the difference between component and directive. In your case you might need shared component 
>    instead of directive